# MySQL trigger to insert into another table before delete operation

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I've written something like this and this is not working. How?

```
mysql> create trigger deleteStudentTrigger
-> before delete on tblStudent for each row
-> begin
-> insert into tblDeletedStudents select * from tblStudent where StudentId = new.StudentId;
-> end;$
```

> ERROR 1363 (HY000): There is no NEW row in on DELETE trigger

Comment: The error message says it all!

Comment: Yeah, I know. I posted that to tell what I tried.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the error, there is no NEW row, only OLD (because when you delete something, it's not new you know)
So it should be

```
mysql> create trigger deleteStudentTrigger
-> before delete on tblStudent for each row
-> begin
-> insert into tblDeletedStudents select * from tblStudent where StudentId = old.StudentId;
-> end;$
```

For more info refer to MySQL documentation

Comment: No error.  But INSERT operation to tblDeletedStudents not happening.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `insert into tblDeletedStudents values (old.StudentId, old.anothercolumn, ...)`?

Comment: `insert select...` is also possible. Well in your case I would test separately if the insert itself is ok (meaning  table schema is the same for both tables)